# I get values from ArrayList and bind these values to dynamic TableRow

Tags: android

I get values from ArrayList and bind these values to dynamic TableRow.

I follow this Link "[How to bind data from ArrayList to TableLayout in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402140/how-to-bind-data-from-)

arraylist-to-tablelayout-in-android".

My code :

```
 ArrayList<SetAttendance> lst= (ArrayList<SetAttendance>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("shahid");    

    for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++)
    {
        TableRow row=new TableRow(this); //Table Row:
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new  TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    row.setLayoutParams(lp);

     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
     //@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

    ArrayList<SetAttendance> att=(ArrayList<SetAttendance>)lst.get(i);
     //The above line gives an error .Cannot cast from SetAttendance to  ArrayList<SetAttendance>

    TextView tv0=new TextView(this);
    tv0.setTextSize(10);
    tv0.setText(att.get(0).toString());
    row.addView(tv0);

    TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
    tv1.setTextSize(10);
    tv0.setText(att.get(1).toString());
    row.addView(tv1);

    TextView tv2=new TextView(this);
    tv2.setTextSize(10);
    tv0.setText(att.get(2).toString());
    row.addView(tv2);


    TextView tv3=new TextView(this);
    tv3.setTextSize(10);
    tv0.setText(att.get(3).toString());
    row.addView(tv3);

    TextView tv4=new TextView(this);
    tv4.setTextSize(10);
    tv0.setText(att.get(4).toString());
    row.addView(tv4);

    TextView tv5=new TextView(this);
    tv5.setTextSize(10);
    tv0.setText(att.get(5).toString());
    row.addView(tv5);


    tl.addView(row);

    }
```

SetAttendance:

public class SetAttendance implements Serializable
{

```
String subject;
int monday;
int tuesday;
int wedday;
int thursday;
int friday;
public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}
public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}
public int getMonday() {
    return monday;
}
public void setMonday(int monday) {
    this.monday = monday;
}
public int getTuesday() {
    return tuesday;
}
public void setTuesday(int tuesday) {
    this.tuesday = tuesday;
}
public int getWedday() {
    return wedday;
}
public void setWedday(int wedday) {
    this.wedday = wedday;
}
public int getThursday() {
    return thursday;
}
public void setThursday(int thursday) {
    this.thursday = thursday;
}
public int getFriday() {
    return friday;
}
public void setFriday(int friday) {
    this.friday = friday;
}


@Override
 public String toString()
 {       
return  getSubject()+getMonday()+getTuesday()+getWedday()+getThursday()+getFriday();                
  }
```

}

Comment: can you be more clear! what's your problem?

Comment: when i declare this line "ArrayList<SetAttendance> att=(ArrayList<SetAttendance>)lst.get(i);" It gives me error "Cannot cast from SetAttendance to  ArrayList<SetAttendance>"

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of you are casting SetAttendance object to SetAttendance arraylist.So
Change this

```
ArrayList<SetAttendance> att=(ArrayList<SetAttendance>)lst.get(i);
```

to

```
SetAttendance att = lst.get(i);
```

Comment: Now this code gives error "att.get(0).toString()","att.get(1).toString()" and so on.

Comment: what is in SetAttendance class?

Comment: In this class Setter and getter methods are define.

Comment: means what fields you use in SetAttendance class.Please post SetAttendance  in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem...

**activity_main.xml**

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">


</TableLayout>

**MainActivity.java**

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private TableLayout tableLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);

        ArrayList<String> lst= new ArrayList<String>();
        lst.add("One");
        lst.add("Two");
        lst.add("Three");
        lst.add("Four");
        lst.add("Five");

        for(int i=0;i<lst.size();i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setTextSize(12);
            textView.setText(lst.get(i));
            row.addView(textView);

            tableLayout.addView(row);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how to set columns width in this method

Comment: new TableRow.LayoutParams(width,height);

Comment: it gives combine result.there is no space between columns.I need six columns